# What is the meaning of "%d:%02d" in `printf`?

Tags: java

I have written the following code to convert hours into minutes. I got some help from the internet but I'm not 100% sure what "%d:%02d" means?

```
package time;

public class TimeAssignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This program will convert hours into minutes
        int time = 120;
        int hours = time / 60; 
        int minutes = time % 60;
        System.out.printf("%d:%02d", hours, minutes);
    }

}
```

Comment: read up on string formatting ex -http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-format-example/

Comment: nice question to get idea

Answer (score 11):

> Even though I'm not 100% sure what “%d:%02d” means

Here you go:

- `%d` means an integer
- `:` is a :
- `%02d` means an integer, left padded with zeros up to 2 digits.

More info at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: Great answer to understand

Answer (score 0):

These are simply the way of printing the numbers. Look at this post [java specifiers](http://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet) to understand what specifiers you are using.

In simple words, %d is an integer that in your case is "hours" and %02d is an integer that is shown as "xx" taken from the variable "minutes"

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for PrintStream (which is what out is) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)

shows what this format string should contain here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Answer (score 0):

"d" is "decimal" integer, there are also "o" for octal integer and "x"/"X" for hexadecimal integer. The rest is as Janos explained.

Answer (score 0):

%2d outputs a decimal (integer) number that fills at least 2 character spaces, padded with empty space. And %d is similar to the %2d but it consists only one character space.
[Learn more from here about this %d, %02d, %f etc](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-meaning-of-2d-6-2f-or-anything-similar-in-C-programming)
E.g.: 5 → " 5", 120 → "120"

Answer (score 0):

In this question when we are talking about `%d` we are talking about the hours, the `:` is the : on digital clocks, and by the `%02d` we mean the minutes padded down with 0s on the left side up to two digits.

Therefore, `%d:%02d` means `hr:min`.